# Can't use .get function on Map

Tags: reactjs

I want to get values from the Map and for each of them make a tag, but when I'm trying to do .get function on Map passed from App.js it shows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: playerData.get is not a function
    at PlayerStats (PlayerStats.jsx:16:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)
```

Here is my file where is the problem:

```
const PlayerStats = ({ playerData }) => {

    console.log(playerData);
    console.log(playerData.get("0"));
    return (
        <main>
            <div/>
            <Grid container justify="center" spacing={4}>
            
            </Grid>
        </main>
)
```

and the App.js:

```
const App = () => {

    const [ playerData, setPlayerData ] = useState([]);


    const handlePlayerData = () => {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
                var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                let index = 0;
                var playerDatas = new Map();
                result.data.forEach(function(element) {
                    var dane = JSON.parse(element.Data);
                    
                    var mapa = new Map();
                    mapa.set("isOnline", dane.isOnline);
                    mapa.set("Name", element.Name);
                    
                    playerDatas.set(index, mapa);
                    
                    index++;
                })
                
                setPlayerData(playerDatas);
            }
        }
        http.open("GET", "https://example.com/", true);
        http.send();
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        handlePlayerData();
        
    }, []);

    return (
        
        <div>
            <PlayerStats playerData={playerData} />
        </div>
        
    );
}
```

Though, when `console.log(playerData);` it normally shows a map on console. I've check that the requested value is on the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing `playerData` as an array at the beginning.

```
const [ playerData, setPlayerData ] = useState([]);
```

Can you try changing the above line as

```
const [ playerData, setPlayerData ] = useState(new Map());
```